# What information from a glm summary do you include in your results

Tags: generalized-linear-model, reporting

I ran a glm looking at population changes over years, and am unsure which results I need to include for a poster presentation. I understand the p value is important for significance but other than that what numbers are necessary and how would I report them?

[image: img]

I do not completely understand what each of the values mean. I am trying to show how populations have changed over the years. I am trying to say something in a university poster along the lines of "I found there to be an overall increase in the population from 2015-2021 (p=0.00155)" but I'm unsure what else would go in the brackets.

Comment: What is the reason you are doing the regression? What do you want to learn from your model? Those will drive what you want to include on the poster.

Comment: Do you understand what each of those numbers mean?

Comment: Answer depends on a lot of things, for instance the audience for the presentation! Please edit to tell us!

Comment: I do not fully understand what the number mean. I am trying to show changes in a population over years given patrol data. I am presenting at a university conference.

Answer (score 2):

The information you include on a poster depends on what you want to demonstrate and the contextual knowledge of your audience.  Since your goal is to show the change in the population of lemurs over the years, there are a few basic things I would suggest you include:

- A **time-series plot** showing the lemur population each year.
- Your **point estimate** for the regression coefficient `years` and an appropriate **confidence interval** around this point.  (A confidence interval is typically more useful than giving a p-value for the hypothesis test for a non-zero coefficient; see [Wasserstein and Lazar 2016](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2016.1154108#.Vt2XIOaE2MN).)

You should ensure that you are happy with your model and make some overall commentary on the fit of the model and whether you think it represents the data well.  If you are presenting to a statistically-skilled audience, and you wish to go into more detail on your model and its fit properties, you could further augment this with some information about the overall goodness-of-fit of your model (e.g., McFadden's coefficient of determination) and possibly some plots of deviance residuals.  This would usually be excessive for a poster presentation but it might be part of an underlying paper or supplementary material for the presentation.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the paper.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the estimate and standard error, for sure, not just the p-value.  The estimate of the increase per year and its precision are important, too.

Comment: To be clear, that data would be from the "year" row, not the intercept right?

Comment: Yes, though if you want people to be able to use the model, you need to give both, e.g. by presenting Lemurs=Intercept+Slope*Year. This is uncommon for posters, though. So you could also go with: "I found there to be an overall increase in the population from 2015-2021 (Slope(SE)=0.06(0.02), p=0.00155).".